# SQL - Different joins regarding to column value

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have schema, where tables are created for flexible implementations. Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
1. Customer

- CUSTOMER_ID
- NAME

2. Account

- ACCOUNT_ID
- ACCOUNT_TYPE
- IBAN

3. Dummy_table

- Dummy_table_id
- FK_CUSTOMER_ID
- FK_ACCOUNT_ID
- TABLE_NAME
```

I want to implement schema logic in JOIN clause. What is the best way to implement this:

```
if (TABLE_NAME == "CUSTOMER") then {
  JOIN WITH CUSTOMER TABLE USING FK_CUSTOMER_ID
} else {
  JOIN WITH ACCOUNT TABLE USING FK_ACCOUNT_ID
}
```

Comment: Explain your requirements and the business rules properly.

Comment: Lalit, please check pseudo code.

Comment: And that is what is not clear. Where exactly is this code going to be implemented? What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to refer to a database table **dynamically**? From where is the table name passed to your IF construct? what happens if no table name is passed, or some trash value is passed? Please explain your requirement properly.

Comment: It is written - I want an SQL query, and I want to implement IF construct in JOIN clause... So it means table name is passed from Dummy_table column...

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you can't.  SQL doesn't work that way.  You could potentially use dynamic SQL to construct one of two different queries or you could construct two different queries statically and `UNION ALL` them together.  Your comment about "flexible implementation" and wanting to dynamically determine which table to join to, though, implies to me that you're not building your data model properly.  If that's the case, I'd strongly suggest reconsidering the model before making your code terribly complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this somehow using outer joins:

```
select dt.dummy_table_id,
       dt.table_name,
       c.customer_id, 
       c.name, 
       a.account_id,
       a.account_type,
       a.iban
from dummy_table dt
  left join customer c 
         on c.customer_id = dt.fk_customer_id 
        and dt.table_name = 'CUSTOMER'
  left join account a 
         on a.account_id = dt.fk_account_id 
        and dt.table_name = 'ACCOUNT'
```

This will give you `NULL` values for those columns that did not match. It will however give you *two* result rows from the `dummy_table` for those "dummy rows" that contain a `customer_id` **and** an `account_id`.

But you didn't specify what the output is you want, so I don't know if that is a problem for you.

But I do agree with Justin's comment: this does not sound like a good idea.